# Fire onChange when a changed field has not lost focus, but form was saved

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

CRM 2015 (and possibly other versions) seems to have a bug as follows:

1. A field is registered with an `onChange` handler.
2. The user changes this field, and:
3. The user immidiately clicks save. That is, before clicking the save button, the user neither presses the Enter key nor clicking somewhere on the form to explicitly loose focus.

The result is that the `onChange` handler of this field is not fired.

What can be done to fire the unfired `onChange` handler in a supported way?

Comment: if it is a input field , you can use `onKeyDown` event .

Comment: Can you use oninput ? that is triggered by paste too

Comment: @mplungjan, no, unfortunately, that's an unsupported way of doing client side on Dynamics CRM.

Comment: I found this when I search for CRM onchange: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmtipsfromadeveloper/archive/2017/05/02/ms-crm-xrm-page-getattribute-quot-attribute-quot-fireonchange-jstip4

Comment: @HeyJude did you try my recommendation?

Comment: @Arun Vinoth, I actually found out I was wrong, and that `onChange` does fire

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong, `onChange` does fire.

Answer (score 0):

Call it if it exists:

```js
document.getElementById("field1").onchange=function() { console.log("change handler called") }

document.getElementById("form1").onsubmit=function() {
   this.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(function(fld) {
     if (fld.onchange) fld.onchange();
   })  
}
```

```html
<form id="form1">
<input type="text" id="field1" />
<input  type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's unsupported on Dynamics CRM. One must use the client-side SDK API to get a field control, or register events

Comment: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmtipsfromadeveloper/archive/2017/05/02/ms-crm-xrm-page-getattribute-quot-attribute-quot-fireonchange-jstip4

Comment: It would have been trivial to use `fireOnChange`, except on the scenario I depicted, where it seems there's no supported way to know which field to call it upon.

Answer (score 0):

Good catch. This should be resolved by user training.   Otherwise we have to circumvent by trapping & completing the `preventDefault` of `onSave` event, check `isDirty` of attributes, then `fireOnchange` and then explicit save event trigger.

As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/events/attribute-onchange) says focus has to lose for `onChange` to trigger:

> The OnChange event occurs in the following situations:
>       •   Data in a form field has changed and focus is lost.

Comment: This isnt the case though, if i update a field the onchange still fires, and if i unfocus it fires again :(